# Multiple servo motors with serial commands

Tags: serial, pwm, servo

I am trying to control multiple servo motors with a Raspberry Pi. I am using a USB to TTL cable for this. I am currently sending following serial commands for the movement.

- --> gpio -g mode 18 pwm
- --> gpio pwm-ms
- --> gpio pwmc 192
- --> gpio pwmr 2000

So we set the frequency for the port 18. Similarly I repeat the steps for 12 and 21 where I have connected two other motors.

- --> gpio -g pwm 18 100
- --> gpio -g pwm 12 100

after this command,
the movement is seen only for the Motor at pin 18 and not for the motor at 12.

How can I correct this? Is there any different frequency to be used?
[image: see the attached image for the block diagram]

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.  You mention a dongle but then detail the commands of the wiringPi utility gpio which acts directly on the Pi GPIO.  What is the dongle doing?

Comment: The dongle is used for the serial communication between the port (for laptop) and the TX RX for the raspberry pi. I am trying to send serial commands from the terminal. To mention: these commands work perfectly for the serial communication with a single motor. Controlling multiple motors is the issue.

Comment: Log on to the Pi and use the commands directly.  Pointless trying to diagnose remote faults.

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you are doing.  Could you provide  photo(s) showing the Pi and connections to the servos?